# Access 2007 VBA Copying Records to Same Table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

So I have been scratching my head for awhile on this issue and although it seems simple in theory I am having a tough time implementing it in VBA.

Some background on the project will be needed to understand what i am trying to do

So our database/application is meant to keep track of how we test a version of software, what the results are, and if the tests were done properly. we have a specific set of scripts that we use from version to version.

In the database we have a table that list these scripts without assigning them to a specific version of software.

then we have a form where you select the version of software you are running against.

**here is the problem i am encountering**

when you have selected a software version I want to have a button that you click and it takes all the associated test scripts copies them and assigns the selected software version IF THIS HASNT BEEN DONE YET. this will allow you to make notes for the specific script that can differ from version to version.

I am currently trying to do this with a union query and have experimented with using the append query but haven had any luck, with the code snippet that i am putting below the results i get when i click the button to execute the assigning of the software version it alerts the proper "Test Script", PROC_CHECK_ID and "Software Version" but then i get a strange prompt that sais "Enter Paramater Value" and it sais the "Test Script Name" with a text field, this goes into an infite loop where i can just keep entering values in the text field.

Here is my code

```
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim unionquery As String

 Dim CURRENT_SOFTWARE_VERSION As String

 CURRENT_SOFTWARE_VERSION = Me.Parent.[Software Version].Value


 unionquery = "select [Test Script] , [PROC_CHECK_ID], [Software Version] from (FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS inner join FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_CHECK on FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS.TEST_CASE_ID = FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_CHECK.TEST_CASE_ID) inner join FORMAL_CERT_SOFTWARE_VERSION on FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS.TEST_CASE_ID = FORMAL_CERT_SOFTWARE_VERSION.TEST_CASE_ID where PROC_CHECK_ID=" & Me.PROC_CHECK_ID & " AND [Software Version]=""" & CURRENT_SOFTWARE_VERSION & """ "


 ' Debug.Print unionquery

 Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(unionquery, dbOpenForwardOnly)

 If Not (rs1.EOF And rs1.BOF) Then

    Do Until rs1.EOF = True
        ' MsgBox " " & rs1![Test Script] & ", " & rs1![PROC_CHECK_ID] & ", " & rs1![Software Version] & " "

        INSERT_INTO_TEST_SCRIPTS = "insert into FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS([Test Script], [PROC_CHECK_ID_FK], [Software_Version], [TEST_CASE_ID]) values(" & rs1![Test Script] & ", " & rs1!PROC_CHECK_ID & ", " & rs1![Software Version].Value & ", " & Me.TEST_CASE_ID & ")"

        ' APPEND QUERY THAT THROWS INTO AN INFINITE LOOP *NEEDS WORK* INSERT_INTO_TEST_SCRIPTS = "INSERT INTO FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS([Test Script], [PROC_CHECK_ID_FK], [Software_Version], [TEST_CASE_ID]) SELECT FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS.[Test Script], " & rs1!PROC_CHECK_ID & ",  " & rs1![Software Version].Value & ", FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS.TEST_CASE_ID FROM FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS WHERE FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS.TEST_CASE_ID = " & Me.TEST_CASE_ID & " "

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
          DoCmd.RunSQL INSERT_INTO_TEST_SCRIPTS
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop

 End If
```

I appreciate any help and am willing to completely rework this mechanic, i am probably over complicating this : /

thanks!

Comment: It looks like you quote Software Version in the first query but not the second.  Also, usually the "Enter Parameter Value" dialog opens up if you have a misspelling, and you didn't intend for it.

Comment: Also, your "unionquery" doesn't have a `UNION` in it, so I wouldn't call it a "unionquery".  I think it would simply be easier to use a query with criteria to check if the software version is null.  Something like this: `"UPDATE FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS SET [Software Version]=""" & Me.Parent.[Software Version].Value & """ WHERE [Software Version] Is Null;"`  ...I think I simply misunderstood your explanation, so that may not be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first SELECT query (`unionquery`) has quotes around the value for [Software Version], indicating that it is a text field. However, your subsequent INSERT query (`INSERT_INTO_TEST_SCRIPTS`) omits the quotes. Therefore, the INSERT query is treating the *value* you are trying to insert as the *name* of some other field, and since no other field exists with that name you are getting the parameter prompt.

Your code might be a bit cleaner (and more reliable) if you did a Recordset insert instead of "gluing together" an INSERT statement. That approach would look something like this:

```vbs
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT * FROM FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS", _
        dbOpenDynaset)
rs2.AddNew
rs2![Test Script] = rs1![Test Script]
rs2![PROC_CHECK_ID_FK] = rs1!PROC_CHECK_ID
rs2![Software_Version] = rs1![Software Version]
rs2![TEST_CASE_ID] = Me.TEST_CASE_ID
rs2.Update
rs2.Close
Set rs2 = Nothing
```

Comment: This is great! thanks Gord, a coouple strange things are occuring though.... 1.) it does assign the software version but it creates it multiple times? something strange is occuring with the loop i believe because it is random 2.) it wont let me assign a software version past the first one, i get a strange syntax error?